# Conditionally redirect to different dashboards based on user permissions in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two types of users in my project; students and teachers.

I have given the teachers access to course material for the students. Problem is I have buttons in the course material that I initially built for the students. When they click the button they are redirected to their dashboard. However, since teachers have access to the same pages when they click said button they get an error message because they cannot be redirected to the student dashboard because of limited permissions.

How would I go about making the button conditional. So if the user has student permissions they would be redirected to their dashboard and if the user has teacher permissions they would be redirected to their dashboard.

This is the html button on the curriculum content

```
<div data-scroll-watch><h3><a href="{% url 'students:app-student-dashboard' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Back to your Dashboard</a></h3></div>
```

and my students views:

```
@login_required
@student_required
@check_is_allow
def dashboard(request):
    # if request.user.is_allow:
    return render(request, 'classroom/students/app-student-dashboard.html')
    # else:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required
@check_is_allow
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_allow and request.user.has_perm("student") :

        return render(request, 'classroom/students/app-student-dashboard.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-teacher-dashboard.html')
```